# What is the XML syntax for mapping a nested class in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, nested-class

Suppose you have the following class definitions:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public class Key
    {
        public virtual OtherEntity Other { get; set; }
        public virtual int Index { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            // something here...
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // something here...
        }
    }

    public virtual Key Id { get; set; }
}

public class OtherEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then you would like to have a mapping file similar to the one below:

```
<class name="SomeEntity" table="SOME">

  <composite-id name="Id" class="SomeEntity.Key">
    <key-many-to-one name="Other" column="OTHER_ID" class="OtherEntity" />
    <key-property name="Index" column="INDEX" type="int" />
  </composite-id>

</class>

<class name="OtherEntity" table="OTHER">

  <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>

</class>
```

Trying to initialize NHibernate results in an `NHibernate.MappingException` being thrown, whith the message of *"could not find class: SomeEntity.Key"*. Most probably the problem is with the `class="SomeEntity.Key"` attribute. I was unable to find the proper syntax for referencing a nested class.

Also I would like to get a hint where else should I have been looking for the answer (I couldn't find the answer in the "NHibernate in Action" book, for example). What is your preferred resource for such questions about to NHibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the CLR syntax for inner classes:

```
<composite-id name="Id" class="SomeEntity+Key">
...
```

Comment: Exactly. So we have documented it for the future generations ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainClass
{
  public virtual long MainKey {get; set;}
  public virtual SubClass SubInstance {get; set;}

  public class SubClass
  {
    public virtual long SubKey {get;set;}
  }
}
```

can be mapped as:

```
<class name="MainClass" table="Main">
  <id name="MainKey" column="MainId" type="Int64">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <many-to-one name="SubInstance" class="MainClass+SubClass" Column="SubId"/> 
</class>

<class name="MainClass+SubClass" table="Sub">
  <id name="SubKey" column="SubId" type="Int64">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
</class>
```